# GDI+ error on Bitmap.Save

Tags: c#

Ive managed to get something like this to work in another project but not on my current.
The file locks and cannot be overwritten when saving again even though i dispose of the b bitmap before calling save. Any idea of what i might be doing wrong?

```
Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("image.png");
Bitmap bClone = (Bitmap)b.Clone();

    // modify bClone here..

b.Dispose();
b = null;
GC.Collect();

bClone.Save("image.png");
```

Comment: FYI, Dispose() will immediately free the memory of your bitmap. The call to GC.Collect() is unnecessary and generally looked down on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Clone" method doesn't do what you want.  You can use the Bitmap's copy constructor instead to create a separate image that contains the same pixels.

```
Bitmap bClone = null;
using (Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("image.png"))
{
    bClone = new Bitmap(b);
    // modify bClone here..
}

bClone.Save("image.png");
bClone.Dispose();
```

Comment: What does the clone method do? :)

Answer (score 0):

Using FromFile you really don't have any control over the lifetime of the file object. Try FromStream instead.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours looking for a solution and trying different combinations, it appears that there is some issue of saving an image on a stale image.  What am doing is creating a list of scanned documents, saving the scanned image as a PictureBox in a FlowLayoutPanel.  That all works great, as I can click the various documents and they show up on a larger picture box.  But when I tried to save the images by going through the FlowLayoutPlanel.Controls collection, I would get the GDI+ error on save.

What I ended up doing, while not elegant, but it does work, it to create a new bitmap and making sure I tell the save that it's a jpeg it's saving.  Here is the code (vb.net 2022 - 17.8.7) that loops through the FlowLayoutPanel (imageCollection):

```vb
idx = 1
For Each pb As PictureBox In imageCollection.Controls
    Dim bmp = New Bitmap(pb.Image)
    bmp.Save(ClientDir & "\" & thisDoc.ClientDocumentID.ToString("D7") & "-" & idx.ToString("D2") & ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    idx += 1
Next
```

As far as not being able to save pb directly, who knows.  But the data (.image) must be transferred to a new bitmap, so my guess it's a memory issue somewhere.  Because the image is definitely there, as I can put it back into the larger PictureBox, and this code does save all of the images in the collection.